# How to change character set in an InnoDB table with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, innodb, collation

I have set of InnoDB tables having foreign keys, I want to change default character set of these table from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_general_ci`, I tried running below query:

```
ALTER TABLE test.PAYMENT DROP FOREIGN KEY PAYMENT_ibfk_1;
```

But it gives me this error:

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './test/#sql-1fa_24f43' to './test/PAYMENT' (errno: 150)
```

I have tried executing this alter by set `foreign_key_checks=0`; and even by disabling keys but still get the same error.

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; totally works for me with MySQL 5.6.19b, InnoDB tables, converting from latin1 to utf8,utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: @Vajk this is quite possible because of the version difference as i as doing it on MySQL-5.5.25. Thanks for mentioning that it worked in MySQL-5.6

Comment: This also saved me in RDS for MariaDB 10.5.8.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved it by dropping foreign keys from all reference tables and main tables

```
 alter table test.PAYMENT drop foreign key PAYMENT_ibfk_1;
 alter table test.ORDER_DETAILS drop foreign key ordr_dets_ibfk_1;
 alter table test.TRANSACTION  drop foreign key transaction_ibfk_1;
```

Then later altered all tables and changed character set

```
 alter table  test.PAYMENT CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
 alter table  test.TRANSACTION CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
 alter table  test.ORDER_DETAILS CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

then again applied foreign keys

```
alter table niclient.PAYMENT add foreign key PAYMENT_ibfk_1 (paymentTransId)  references `TRANSACTION` (`transId`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
alter table niclient.ORDER_DETAILS add foreign key ordr_dets_ibfk_1 (ordrDetTransId) REFERENCES `TRANSACTION` (`transId`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
alter table niclient.TRANSACTION add foreign key transaction_ibfk_1 (transCompId)  REFERENCES `COMPANY_DETAILS` (`compId`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It perfectly worked fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure about what you are doing,

you can eventually evaluate to play with the option that disables foreign key checks, available on the InnoDB engine.

Example:

```sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

ALTER TABLE ...;
ALTER TABLE ...;
ALTER TABLE ...;
ALTER TABLE ...;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Relevant documentation:

https://mariadb.com/docs/server/ref/mdb/system-variables/foreign_key_checks/

As usual, do a backup before doing this kind of things.